# Is there a way to schedule an update to an offline Google Sheets document using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Using Google apps script, I would like to schedule a refresh of data in Google Sheets, when the document is not open.

I can create a time-based trigger (as follows) , but it is not attached to a specific spreadsheet. Is there any way to create a time-based trigger that is attached to a specific spreadhseet?

```
const trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onTriggerTimeBased')
    .timeBased()
    .onMonthDay(1)
    .everyHours(1)
    .create();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*not attached*"?

Answer (score 1):

The `'onTriggerTimeBased'` string in the function is the name of the function that would be triggered after the time you entered so you can get the spreadsheet in the function using
`SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId)`
where `ssId` is a variable that stores a string representation of the id of the spreadsheet.
The Id of the spread sheet is the string that comes after `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/` in the URL of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like the answer is no, you cannot attach the trigger to a specific spreadsheet. When the trigger fires, it would be necessary to get the ssId from a database or somewhere else where it was stored permanently, correct?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand what you meant by attaching a trigger to a specific spreadsheet. In order to manipulate a spreadsheet in google app script you either need it to be active or to get his id from somewhere. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?